# how to select each fourth div in collection using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have gallery alike div container with many item divs inside. I want to select each fourth or in programming therms itemID % 4 == 0 item.

How can i do that with jQuery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('#select_id:nth-child(4n)')
```

[**Here is a demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/D5tQC/)

Comment: Won't it select only 4 div ? i want element % 4 == 0 ?

Comment: @eugeneK: Did you check the demo? No, it won't select only the fourth div, but all the DIVs whose modulus will equal to 0.

Comment: Sorry, missed 4n, thought you like others posted 4 only... thanks

Answer (score 1):

By using the :nth-child selector http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

Comment: Won't it select only 4 div ? i want element % 4 == 0

Comment: http://www.pamaya.com/jquery-selectors-and-attribute-selectors-reference-and-examples/

Answer (score 0):

In this way:

```
var div = $("div:eq(3)");
```

Comment: Won't it select only 4 div ? i want element % 4 == 0

Answer (score 0):

You could use filter -

```
$('div').filter(function(index) {
    return (index + 1) % 4 === 0;
})
```